# Sum records values in Django

Tags: python, django

I defined couple models in my app:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url     = models.URLField()
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Cost(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    cost    = models.FloatField()
    date    = models.DateField()
```

I want to sum costs for each project and render values `view.py`:

```
from mypm.costs.models import Project, Cost
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum

def index(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('index.html',...
```

What is the best way of solving such aggregation in Django ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alexander's solution will give you the right result, but with one query for each project. Use
`annotate` to do the whole thing in a single query.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

annotated_projects = Project.objects.all().annotate(cost_sum=Sum('cost__cost'))
for project in annotated_projects:
    print project.title, project.cost_sum
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it. There may be a more efficient way to write the get_total_cost function... but this should work.

Models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.URLField()
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        tot = 0
        for cost in Cost.objects.filter(project=self):
            tot += cost.cost
        return tot

class Cost(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

View:

```
from mypm.costs.models import Project, Cost
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'projects',Project.objects.all()},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for project in projects %}
<p>{{project.title}}: {{project.get_total_cost}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is pretty basic stuff.

Take some time and go through the Django [tutorials](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) and [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [aggregate](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-args-kwargs).

```
from django.db.models import Sum

for project in Projects.objects.all():
  print project, project.cost_set.all().aggregate(sum_of_cost=Sum('cost'))['sum_of_cost'] or 0
```